# How To Access Spring Bean name?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

```
@Named("myUniqueName") 
public class ReportDashboardDao implements DashboardDAO{ 
//STUFF 
}
```

how can i access the string inside @Named tag when i am injecting DashboardDAO like this :

```
@Named
public class DshboardDaoConsumer(){

@Inject List<DashboardDAO> dashboardDAO;
//STUFF
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't. You're injecting by type. After injection has been done, Spring does not leave behind any relation between the bean's object and the bean's name.

You might want to check out [`ApplicationContext#getBeanNamesByType()`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/ListableBeanFactory.html#getBeanNamesForType-java.lang.Class-) depending on what you want to do.

Comment: thanks. what about beanNameAware interface? or is it complete different thing?

Comment: Yes, you can use `BeanNameAware` and implement `setBeanName()` and then provide a `getBeanName` to access the name, but what @SotiriosDelimanolis is saying is that you cannot access the value you're providing in the `@Named` annotation.

Comment: As of now it is: `ctx.getBeanNamesForType()`

Answer (score 10):

Use a Map instead

```
@Inject 
Map<String, DashboardDao> dashBoardDaos;
```

This will inject a `Map` with bean names as keys and daos as values.

Of course, you could also read the annotation value from class instances.

Answer (score 4):

By implementing [BeanNameAware](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanNameAware.html).

```
@Named("myUniqueName") 
public class ReportDashboardDao implements DashboardDAO, BeanNameAware{ 
      //STUFF 

     private String beanName;

     @Override 
     public Void setBeanName(String beanName) {
        this.beanName = beanName;
     } 

}
```

So that Spring can inject the beanName into the bean. If you add a public `String getBeanName();`  in your `DashboardDAO` interface, `DashboardDaoConsumer` will be able to obtain it.

In this particular case, Spring will inject the name you specified in the annotation.